Domain Adaptation on non-normalized data - how to denormalize as the last step
Reading Domain Adaptation data I often encounter "assuming we have normalized data ..."
My question is. If the data is not normalized, and I would like to adapt my data what exactly is the right way of denormalizing? E.g. I would like to make a meaningful plot of adapted data
The full process in my understanding is:

compute and save mean_source, std_source, mean_target, std_target
normalize source and target and obtain source_normalized, target_normalized
perform domain adaptation and obtain source_normalized_adapted
now denormalize by multiplying with std and adding the mean

BUT which of the means / stds do I take?
Normally, I would say source_denormalized = source_normalized * std_source + mean_source. But as we are trying to adapt data to a new domain, it kinda sounds more like I should actually add the target mean  and std.
Thanks for your input
